Is the real part of the Eta function bounded by $2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}} $
Consider the series defined by
\begin{equation}
f(\alpha,\beta) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}\cos(\beta\ln(n))} 
\end{equation}
is it true that $$f(\alpha,\beta) \le 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}} $$ Here is my attempt if we define $\mathcal{I}_\beta$ and $\mathcal{J}_\beta$ as the following $$\mathcal{I}_\beta = \{n\in \mathbb{N}:~ \cos(\beta\ln(n))> 0\}$$ and $$\mathcal{J}_\beta = \{n\in \mathbb{N}:~ \cos(\beta\ln(n))< 0\}$$ and assume $\cos(\beta\ln(n))\neq 0$ for some $(\beta,n)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{N}$ then we can write $f$ as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(\alpha,\beta) &=  \sum_{n\in \mathcal{I}_\beta}^{}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}\cos(\beta\ln(n))} + \sum_{n\in \mathcal{J}_\beta}^{}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}\cos(\beta\ln(n))}\\
& = \sum_{n\in \mathcal{I}_\beta}^{}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}|\cos(\beta\ln(n))|} + \sum_{n\in \mathcal{J}_\beta}^{}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\alpha}}|\cos(\beta\ln(n))|}\\
& \le  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}|\cos(\beta\ln(n))|} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\alpha}}|\cos(\beta\ln(n))|}\\
& \le  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\alpha}}}\\
& \le 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

What if $\alpha=1.01$ and $e^{i\beta p}\approx (-1)^{p-1}$ for first many primes $p$?

I'm assuming of course the function converges. So when the real part of the parameter is less then 1 but Greater then 0

And beta can't be any number l. It can't be numbers that give $\cos(\beta\ln(n))=0$ for some $n$

I think a possibile issue is extending the last series to infinity im actually not sure that the inequality stays the same. I'm assuming that the absolute series will be smaller then with a $1$ in numerator because the cosine is bounded by $1$. It might be smaller I kinda took that for granted. We are adding a subset of them so I assume the entire series will be larger then a subset of it

It is well known (Selberg limit theorem) that for example for $\alpha =1/2$ we have both the real and imaginary part of $\eta(\alpha+i\beta)$ grows at least like $c(\log \beta)^{1/2}$ quite a lot of the time (for $\beta>0$ large say), so no bound like the one in the OP can happen then; in general it is easy to see that for fixed $0<\alpha<1$ the real and imaginary parts of $\eta(\alpha+i\beta), \beta \in \mathbb R$ are unbounded too so no bound like the one in the OP can happen then either

Breaking the sum up like this we know the sign of cosine but not the parity of each $n$ in the sum

So the fault was extending to infinity

the inequality $\sum_{n\in \mathcal{I}\beta}^{}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}|\cos(\beta\ln(n))|} \le \sum{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}|\cos(\beta\ln(n))|} $ is incorrect

Seems odd we are adding all the numbers in the second and only like half in the first. The second sum contains the first sum

$1-0+1-0+1-0 >(1-0+1-0+1-0)+0-1+0-1+0-1$ although we are adding only half the numbers in the first sum

I see  weird things can happen at infinity. The second sum does contain the first though kinda strange. Cosine is still at most 1 here and maybe just bounded by $\sum_{n\in I_\beta}^{}{(-1)^{n-1}/n^\alpha}$ why can we not change the cosine to something we can bound

when you add positive and negative terms it is very tricky to bound subsums in terms of the full sum as noted in the example above - nothing to do with cosine per se

We know each cosine term is positive or negative in both sums and not both. we just don't know the sign of (-1)^{n-1} at each point in $I_\beta$. There should be a computable bound maybe breaking it up like this but I failed

The question is whether this inequality on the Dirichlet eta function holds:
$$\Re\eta(\alpha+i\beta)\leq 2\eta(\alpha).$$
It does not hold.
Here is a plot of $\Delta(\alpha,\beta)=2\eta(\alpha)-\Re\eta(\alpha+i\beta)$ as a function of $\beta$ for $\alpha=0.5$. It drops below zero for $4\lesssim\beta\lesssim 7$.

It also fails for $\alpha>1$, for example, for $\alpha=1.2$ and $5\lesssim\beta\lesssim 6$.

Does not seem far away distance looks like a cosine wave
